# How to use Font Awesome CDN with Webpack?

Tags: webpack

I am having trouble using Font Awesome Icons with Webpack. First, I copied the CDN link in the `<head/>` section of the HTML template like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css" 
    integrity="sha512-DTOQO9RWCH3ppGqcWaEA1BIZOC6xxalwEsw9c2QQeAIftl+Vegovlnee1c9QX4TctnWMn13TZye+giMm8e2LwA==" 
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
```

Then I added these lines to my Webpack configuration:

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...other configuration
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(svg|eot|woff|woff2|ttf)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          outputPath: 'fonts',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Also, I added following code in the `main.js` and `main.scss` file:

```js
// main.js
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all.js';
```

```scss
// main.scss
$fa-font-path:'~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts';
@import'~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css';
```

But it doesn't works!